# Map for maximizing sub-window vertically

Tags: vim

How to map this sequence of keys to <kbd>F3</kbd> in Vim: `<Ctrl>+W 9 9 9 +`? That's sequence for maximizing current `:sp` window over the whole screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably use :

```
:noremap <F3> <C-W>_<C-W>\|
```

Where :

- `<C-W>|` maximizes horizontally
- `<C-W>_` maximizes vertically

See `:help window-resize` for other possibilities.